# SQL Server 2008 - Not Always Getting Max

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that should return the `MAX` `CloseDate` from a table that `has many` close dates, `grouped by` the `ShipmentNumber` column.
I seem to be getting more than one `ShipmentNumber` in the results when I include the `Notes` column.

table WorkOrders

```
WorkOrderID, ProjectNumber, ShipmentNumber, CloseDate, WorkOrderNotes
1, 884, 123-01, 2016-04-01, Note A
2, 884, 123-01, 2016-04-02, Note B
3, 884, 123-02, 2016-04-01, Note A
```

table Projects

```
ProjectNumber, Name
884, Project A
```

Query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, WO.ShipmentNumber,MAX(WO.CloseDate) AS CloseDate,
CAST(WO.WorkOrderNotes AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS WorkOrderNotes
FROM DA.dbo.WorkOrders AS WO
LEFT JOIN Projects.dbo.project_primary AS p ON p.id = WO.ProjectNumber
WHERE WO.CloseDate >= '2016-03-01'
AND WO.CloseDate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY WO.ShipmentNumber, p.name, p.id, CAST(WO.WorkOrderNotes AS NVARCHAR(100)) ;
```

Results:

```
884, Project A, 123-01, 2016-04-01, Note A <-- Should not be here
884, Project A, 123-01, 2016-04-02, Note B
884, Project A, 123-02, 2016-04-01, Note A
```

Comment: Could be because of your left join.                                                SQL LEFT JOIN Keyword. The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Irb got this in the comments; you're grouping by `WO.ShipmentNumber` and have different values for this for the first and third line; thus getting both.

If you want only the WO record with the max close date, try this:

```
SELECT p.id
, p.name
, WO.ShipmentNumber
, WO.CloseDate
FROM (
    select ProjectNumber 
    , ShipmentNumber
    , CloseDate
    , CAST(WorkOrderNotes AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS WorkOrderNotes
    , row_number() over (partition by ProjectNumber order by CloseDate desc) r
    from DA.dbo.WorkOrders 
    WHERE WO.CloseDate >= '2016-03-01'
    AND WO.CloseDate IS NOT NULL
) AS WO
LEFT JOIN Projects.dbo.project_primary AS p 
    ON p.id = WO.ProjectNumber
WHERE WO.r = 1 --only return the record with the most max CloseDate
GROUP BY p.id
, p.name
, WO.ShipmentNumber
, WO.WorkOrderNotes
```